# Improve download speed of images from s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, streamlit

I created a Streamlit app that gets and displays images from S3 for labeling purposes. The app is extremely slow! After using the code profiler, I discovered that the following section of code takes the most time (reaches 40-120 seconds).

```
for obj in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="images/"+item_data['Img']):
    object = my_bucket.Object(obj.key)
    file_stream = io.BytesIO()
    object.download_fileobj(file_stream)
    image = Image.open(file_stream)
```

Is there anything that might be done to reduce this time?

Comment: Parallel multipart downloads - but if you have a slow connection to S3 or a lot of images this simply will take some time...

Comment: That code is looping through multiple objects. How many objects is it processing? How large are the objects? Do you really need to download all the files before using them?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, it should find one object, but I use this method as I don't know the extension of the image (imagename.jpg or imagename.JPG) so I search by the image name. 
The images sizes are between 5MB to 16MB. Each time, I download one image.

Comment: You might want to add some `print()` statements to debug where the time is being taken. It is either the `filter()`, or `download_fileobj()`. If there is a _huge_ number of objects in the path, then it would likely be the filter. Please let us know what you find.